# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected strict mode reserved word

Tags: javascript

I have been searching for a while now on what this error means (error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected strict mode reserved word), or how to fix it but I just cannot find anything, so I was hoping that someone here could help? By the way going to bed on this so only gonna read responses (if any) tomorrow.

Here is the line giving me the error:

```
for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) { //(And then the code)
```

FOR PEOPLE WHO NEED CONTEXT:

```
const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas1');

const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

class background {
  draw(){   
    ctx.fillstyle = 'green';
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.fillRect(0,10,800,500);
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.closePath;
  };
};

const Backdrop = new background();

Backdrop.draw();

class artist {
  for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    draw(){
      ctx.fillStyle = 'lime';
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.fillRect(0+i,10,20,15);
      ctx.fill();
      ctx.closePath;
    };
  };
};

const box = new artist();

box.draw();
```

Ok send help, thanks!!

Comment: You cannot have `for` inside a class declaration. Only methods, properties, or constructor.

Comment: Do you know any other way then to repeat this drawing but with the x pos changing each time just a little, without writing it 10 times?

Comment: The `for` line should be inside the `draw()` method.

Comment: Put the for loop inside the `draw()`

Comment: Im sorry im having trouble understanding, could you show an example?

Answer (score 0):

As @Barmar commented you can use the for loop inside your `draw()`.

Here is a working example:

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById('c')
canvas.style.background = 'black'
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d')

class artist {
  draw() {
    ctx.fillStyle = 'lime'
    
    for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      ctx.fillRect(10 + i * 30, 30, 20, 15)
    }
    
  }
}

const box = new artist()
box.draw()
```

```html
<canvas width="400px" height="170px" id="c"></canvas>
```